# CSS issue after moving website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly, I could not find any answers what would solve this (hope simple) issue. So I've just moved the whole website, all its pages and stylesheets to a new directory through my host and now it just cannot load any style for itself. I guess it's about a little problem but already working to find that piece but couldn't get at all.

So to simplify it, in cPanel's File Manager I catched all files and moved to an addon domain like below:

/www/public_html <--- This was the main directory but I moved it to
/www/public_html/addondomainname's directory

The above location is now the current for all pages like index, account, dashboard etc. and all of them are .php files.
Also, I call css sheets to individual pages like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Note that too, there is no full-named links on single pages, I use all my links as they are in-page like so:

```
<a href="mysite.com/help/faq">Help</a>
```

Would be just

```
<a href="./help/faq">Help</a> // Or without the DOT and SLASH
```

And finally I use BS 3 and Font Awesome as sources of my website. I could say it relies on Bootstrap mainly and yes, I included all necessity of script and js implementation within the .

Full code of BS and FA in index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I tried linking the css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite.com/css/styles.css/>
```

But both, with or without the mysite.com href did not work. And yes, the addon domain's directory structured like the root (after public_html/addon) contains index.php, dashboard.php, otherpage.php etc. and folder called css holds all sheets what I would like to use.

Any suggestions would be appreciated guys!

Comment: `href="mysite.com/...."` would mean you're accessing your site with `http://example.com/mysite.com/etc...`?

Comment: Well as it is an addon domain I know if I change the link in the address bar like myrootpage.com/myaddonpage.com is the same if I just type in myaddonpage.com but where's the secret? How to call the css correctly than?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading the CSS in the following methods:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/css/styles.css" />`

Or try:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />`

When loading from your addon domain e.g. http://www.example.com

Comment: Please could you link us to the website, and then I can inspect it for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry to everybody who wasted his/her time trying to help me. The issue occured by my stupidity and everything was just fine. What I did is like I ensured that preventing hotlinking my files e.g. jpg, gif and such as CSS does really work. I've just removed the extension of css to be prevented from hotlinking and it works like a charm. Really, sometimes people do not know what are they doing and again I'm sorry who answered my question!

PS: We should log ourselves what are we doing while remaking any of the projects, stuff or materials.. :)

Best wishes,
Christian